# Stylecop - supress rule for class but not for interface

Tags: .net, stylecop

Is there any way to suppress "1600 Elements must be documented" for class but not for interface?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a global way to enforce it, but you could supress the failure on your class. Pointless if you plan to make a lot of classes this way though.

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1600:ElementsMustBeDocumented")]
```